# java 8 - is there a good way to filter and remove from a map?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to filter several objects from a map as follows:

- Create a new map with the filtered results
- Remove from original map

Currently I do it using two methods

```
Map<String, MyObject > map = scenarioFieldsMap.entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getKey().contains("["))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue()));

scenarioFieldsMap.entrySet().removeIf(e -> e.getKey().contains("["));
```

Is there a better way to filter and remove?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove an element of a HashMap whilst streaming (lambda)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808973/how-to-remove-an-element-of-a-hashmap-whilst-streaming-lambda)

Comment: Why do you need two maps if they will be the same after your op? If you want two distinct instances you can remove the elements from the original map and then use the copy constructor.

Comment: `map.keySet().removeIf(k -> k.contains("["));`

Comment: @AlexisC. They won't be the same. The OP wants to remove some entries from the original map and the new map should contain all the removed entries.

Comment: @Eran Ah yes, the code did not reflect this however. I guess the OP meant `scenarioFieldsMap.entrySet().removeIf(e -> e.getKey().contains("["));`

Comment: @AlexisC.Yes, this must be a typo. Otherwise the OP will end up with an empty map (after removing in the second step all the entries that were added in the first step).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The second step can be more efficient if instead of iterating over all the keys (or entries) you only remove the keys present in the other map :

```
scenarioFieldsMap.keySet().removeAll(map.keySet());
```

I'm assuming you meant to remove the entries from the original `scenarioFieldsMap` and not from the new map that you create in the first step.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly. Can I iterate scenarioFieldsMap only once - removing and creating new collection? Or am I to do it with two iterations?

Comment: @rails I can't think of a way to create the new Map and remove from the old Map in one iteration using Streams. However, if you change your second step as I suggested, it will only iterate over the keys that have to be removed (since each of them can be accessed in expected constant time) and it wouldn't have to run the filtering again.

Answer (score 1):

As a possible alternative you may use a `partitioningBy` collector:

```
Collector<Entry<String, MyObject>, ?, Map<Boolean, Map<String, MyObject>>> collector = 
    Collectors.partitioningBy(e -> e.getKey().contains("["),
                Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
Map<Boolean, Map<String, MyObject>> maps = scenarioFieldsMap.entrySet()
        .stream().collect(collector);
```

This way you don't modify the original map, but create two new maps instead: `maps.get(true)` is the map which keys contain `"["` and `maps.get(false)` contains all the rest.