# Delete from map while adding to an array? (lambda)

Tags: java, lambda

I want to iterate through a Map, running a boolean function on the values and appending the true values to a List. I also want to remove the keys with false values from the map as I do this. How would I accomplish this with a lambda? From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808973/how-to-remove-an-element-of-a-hashmap-whilst-streaming-lambda) I can do the latter but I am not sure how I would combine them in a lambda function.

Edit:
The map is

```
<String, String>
```

and I have a boolean method checkCondition(string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove the values equal to "2".

```
map.entrySet().removeIf(e -> e.getValue().equals("2") ? list.add(e.getValue()) : false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it (although not the only one):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

map = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(t -> checkCondition(t.getValue()))
    .peek(t -> list.add(t.getKey()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Comment: @Andrew updated the answer with the type of the map and including the function.

Comment: the parentheses don't seem to add up, perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: woops, sorry typo, forgot to close the `filter` and the `forEach`

Comment: seeing "cycle inference" error on Map.Entry parts. Switched to initializing a new map, and I am getting an error where it cannot resolve collect

Comment: change the `forEach` for `peek`, forgot that `forEach` doesn't return the stream to be collected

Answer (score 0):

Using a stream you would get a `ConcurrentModificationException`, but you can do it by combining an `Iterator` with a lambda expression.

Example:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    Predicate<String> filter = "foo"::equals;

    myMap.put("a", "foo");
    myMap.put("b", "bar");

    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator = myMap.entrySet().iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, String> element = iterator.next();
        if (filter.test(element.getValue())) {
            myList.add(element.getValue());
        } else {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("List: " + myList);
    System.out.println("Map: " + myMap);
```

The output will be:

```
List: [foo]
Map: {a=foo}
```

"bar" has been removed and "foo" has been added to the list.